# Add url from Custom Field as 'Featured Image'. Code not working

Tags: custom-field, images, post-thumbnails

I'm trying to migrate a site to WP. We have a whole bunch of pictures, and I have done some research and figured -- I think -- my best bet is a CSV import of the data, storing the relative URL of the image as a custom field.

So, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371929/convert-custom-field-image-to-become-featured-image-in-wordpress) --which looks ideal -- and I implemented it thus (in functions.php with a global call added as I was getting a 'no object' error):

```
function store_cf_featured_image() {
global $post,$wpdb;

$uploads = wp_upload_dir();

// Get all attachment IDs and filenames
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'");

// Create an 'index' of attachment IDs and their filenames
$attachments = array();
foreach ($results as $row)
    $attachments[ intval($row->post_id) ] = $row->meta_value;

// Get all featured images
$images = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id, meta_value AS 'url' FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'featured_image'");

// Loop over each image and try and find attachment post
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if (preg_match('#^https?://#', $image->url))
        $image->url = str_replace($uploads['baseurl'], '', $image->url); // get relative URL if absolute

    $filename = ltrim($image->url, '/');

    if ($attachment_ID = array_search($filename, $attachments)) {
        // found attachment, set post thumbnail and delete featured image
        update_post_meta($image->post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_ID);
        delete_post_meta($image->post_ID, 'featured_image');
    }


}


}

add_action( 'init', 'store_cf_featured_image' );
```

However, when I put a link in my custom field 'featured_image', and save it... nothing. No errors, but no nothing. I update the post and come back to it, but the link is still just a link the the custom field and no 'featured image' has been set.

Does anyone have any ideas what the issue might be? an am I right in thinking this will store the image as part of built in 'Media Library', now?

AlsoAlso: Will I be able to adapt this code to pull in Alt text etc for each image from custom fields.

Any input greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Is the code hooked to something? when does it run?

Comment: Aha, I don't know. I'm still pretty new to WP and PHP in general. I thought add_action( 'init', 'store_cf_featured_image' ); would run it? Maybe it isn't running... How do I make sure? (i assume it is runnign because it was throwing up errors before i put in 'globa $past,$wpdb')

Comment: Right sorry, didn't see the `add_action`.

Comment: No worries! So as far as you can see the code looks like it should work? I mean... no glaring errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so you're images are already in a custom field?

you could use the Get the Image plugin.... i know it will pull your thumbnail from a custom field and i *think* it might automatically set it as the featured image, tho it has been a while and i'm not sure of that.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/

Comment: I had a look at Get the Image, it let's you pull images from custom fields. But it doesn't store them or set them as featured (as far as I can see). Ideally I'd like to import all the main images for each post, and attach them using the normal WP media library, then i can get them resized etc automagically as I need and they are available to most plugins

Comment: ambitious. i thought GTI set your image as the featured image, but maybe that is for the ones it 'finds' in the post content? i can't remember.

Comment: Aha. Okay. I've read around this a bit more, and Get the Image doesn't set the 'featured image' but you can use it to make a featured image in an alternate manner! Which, depending on your view of how many DB queries you want to have etc... might be a better way of doing things.

Comment: Either way, this should do what I need at the moment, so many thanks for the responses. If I figure out how to combine Get the Image with WP auto-image resizing for thumbnails etc I'll post back on here! Thanks @helgatheviking!